# Why SMTP sendmail works fast in local but very slow in my dev server Django 1.6

Tags: django, email, python-2.7, sendmail

I am using SMTP sendmail in my project and tried to send a mail using SMTP sendmail. Its works fine and sends mail in 3-4 seconds. But the same code takes around 5 Minutes in dev server. Can you please help me.

In my view function

```
def send_email(subject, message, recipients, contenttype, attachments = []):
    try:
        from_email = "gauravnagpal2002@gmail.com"

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = from_email
        msg['To'] = ",".join(recipients)
        msg.attach( MIMEText(message) )

        for f in attachments:
            part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
            part.set_payload( open(f,"rb").read() )
            Encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f))
            msg.attach(part)        

        server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
        server.sendmail(from_email, recipients, msg.as_string())
        server.quit()
    except Exception, e:
        logger.error(str(e))
```

Can any one helps me to figure it out whats am doing wrong?

Comment: Does that happen just in Django or any other attempt to send an email there is slow too?
 :: 
Try put some timers in your code to see which part is slow.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use django inbuilt email,

Edit settings.py with code below:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Run interactive mode, `python manage.py shell`
Import the EmailMessage module,

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
# Send the email,

email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', t=['mickeyckm@mangooranges.com'])
email.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this probably isn't a django problem (or a python problem, because you're not using django to actually send your e-mail).  I've had a similar problem before by not including my server's fully-qualified name in the hosts file.

Open /etc/hosts and make sure that your fully-qualified domain name of your server maps to the loopback address (127.0.0.1).

If this is your only web server (something like this)

```
127.0.0.1 localhost your.servers.fully.qualified.domain.com
```

Really, though.. We need more information to help you.  If you try this solution (make sure to restart the sendmail daemon) and you're still having problems, open up the log for sendmail (if you're on ubuntu, it's going to be somewhere like  /var/log/mail.log) and take a look at the log entries for when sendmail is called, then update your question with the relevant log entries.

See also:

https://superuser.com/questions/626205/sendmail-very-slow-etc-hosts-configuration/626219#626219

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/sendmail-is-slow-to-send-mail